# Numbers How to show a hidden column?

Tags: numbers

First time working with Numbers and I hid a column by mistake.  How do I show/unhide a column in this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click (or <kbd>control</kbd> + click ) on an adjacent column header letter.  For example "Column D".

Then select **Unhide** from the dialog.

[image: Unhide columns]